# Service sharedpreferences updating value in activity

Tags: android

My service class can edit and store new value of sharedpreferences

so i want to retrieve it in another activity, its working fine.

Now what i would like to do, once service altered sharedpreferences, i want the sharedprefrences value to be updated in activity.

I used timer but it returns nullpointerexception. Any idea why?

Comment: Post any log messages and relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) to monitor changes to your `SharedPreference`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how a timer would help you in the scenario you've described.  You may want to look into other options, such as:

- Using a BroadcastReceiver
- Binding the service to the activity & using the AIDL to define handlers.